# How do I go about setting a varible value from input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, if-statement

I'm new to python, maybe someone can explain this?
Im trying to assign a variable a value depending on yes or no.

```
def direction(decision):
    if decision == "x":
        x_var.set(CW)
    elif decision == "z":
        x_var.set(CCW)
    return


direction(x)

print(x_var)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Where is your yes and no in your example? can you make this clearer?

Comment: do you mean you want to get user input and then set that as a variable? because what you showed us doesn't really mean anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change a variable defined outside a function inside the function you need to bring it into scope using `nonlocal` or `global`, But that is not good practice.

You can return the value you want and assign it directly outside the function call instead.

```py
def direction(decision):
    if decision.lower() == "x":
        return CW
    elif decision.lower() == "z":
        return CCW
    return None

x_var = direction(decision)
```

Comment: If we didn't return anything in the function, `None` is return like always.

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it out, couldnt have from reading, so thank you!